# Run two instances of an SFML C++ app in Xcode

Tags: c++11, xcode6, sfml

I wonder if there is a way of running an app in Xcode,
and then, without closing it, launching another instance of the same app.

I want to know this because I want to create a program for network communication
and need two instances to test how the program behaves.

The program is written in C++ using SFMLs network module.

Obviously, I can get the desired effect by creating a new identical program and running it, but it would be easier if they where the same (save me the copy/paste before each run).

I'm running Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never done this with XCode, but with any other IDE I would simply open the project twice, so two XCode instances are running, both on the same folder. That way you have "shared" code and your changes are automatically there when you recompile and restart both instances.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Running `open -n -a xcode` in terminal opened a second instance and solved my problem, thanks.